# openstack and OVH vRack public ip pool configuration

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron, ovh

We're setting up our own openstack cloud using OVH dedicated sever. We couldn't connect to our openstack instances using public ips. Because OVH allow traffic based on MAC-IP_Address binding match.

We've found this link useful but this is quite outdated.

=> https://dohuyhoang.github.io/openstack/ovh/neutron/2014/07/07/Configure-OpenStack-network-on-OVH.html

We use CentOS 7.7 and the openstack release is centos-release-openstack-stein-1-1.el7.centos.noarch

We have already configure xx.xx.xx.xx/29 public ip pool in neutron.However it doesn't connect from external world.

Anyone has experience in setting up vRack for OpenStack cloud environment ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using vRack, you'll not need to used the MAC to IP Address static binding. However, you'll be limited in the traffic you can use to Internet (two years ago, the public IP traffic inside a vRack was limited to 300 or 500Mbps **for the whole vrack**.

To use vRack, you'll need compatible server (check OVH website for compatibility) and setup the secondary network Interface (vRack compatible servers come with at least two network card, one for the management traffic and one for the vRack traffic) and used it with neutron to host your IP pool.

You'll then need to move the IP Pool to your vRack in the OVH Control Panel.